# VHDL Procedures

Tags: vhdl, procedure

For a class, I was asked to write a VHDL procedure that takes two integer inputs A and B and replaces A with A+B and B with A-B.  I wrote the following program and testbench.  It completes implementation and the Behavioral Syntax check but it will not simulate.  Although I get no errors, I do get some warnings stating that A and B are in combinational feedback loops.  Can someone shed some light on what the problem may be?

Module:

```
 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

 entity Problem2 is
Port ( A : inout  integer;
       B : inout  integer);
 end Problem2;

 architecture Behavioral of Problem2 is

procedure AB (signal A,B: inout integer) is 
begin
A<=A+B after 20 ns;
B<=A-B after 30 ns;
end AB;

begin

AB(A=>A, B=>B);

end Behavioral;
```

TestBench:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY Problem2_test IS
END Problem2_test;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF Problem2_test IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT Problem2
    PORT(
     A : INOUT  integer;
     B : INOUT  integer
    );
END COMPONENT;


--BiDirs
   signal A : integer;
   signal B : integer;
  -- No clocks detected in port list. Replace <clock> below with 
-- appropriate port name 

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: Problem2 PORT MAP (
          A => A,
          B => B
        );

 ABproc: process is
begin
    A<=25;
    B<=22;
    wait;
end process;

END;
```

Comment: That hasn't got any sense...

Answer (score 6):

The problem is:

1. Your component writes to it's own inputs. This is the equivalent of an infinite loop. The reason you've done this is because ....
2. The description of the problem doesn't make sense.

> I was asked to write a VHDL procedure that takes two integer inputs A and B...

Fine

> ...and replaces A with...

What?!

You can't **replace** `A` (or `B`) because you'll get this problem. You could write a procedure that takes two integer inputs, and gives two integer outputs. Those outputs could then feed some registers which then feed the input, but there has to be a register there to break the combinatorial feedback loop.

Answer (score 1):

Don't test it inside a the  `problem2` entity. Just call the procedure straight from your test bench.

(This code is not tested!)

```
ABproc: process is
begin
    A<=25;
    B<=22;
    AB(A, B);
    wait 1 ns;
    assert A = 47;
    assert B = 3;
    wait; -- forever
end process;
```